# Hosting native Android and iOS views in your Flutter app with Platform Views

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to follow the Flutter tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views, but the Java code has errors and doesn't compile. Specifically, NativeViewFactory is defined as having two parameters, but then is called with no parameters. What changes can be made to the code so that it compiles and displays a native Android view in Flutter?

In NativeViewFactory.java:

```
 @NonNull private final BinaryMessenger messenger;
 @NonNull private final View containerView;

 NativeViewFactory(@NonNull BinaryMessenger messenger, @NonNull View containerView) {
    super(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE);
    this.messenger = messenger;
    this.containerView = containerView;
  }
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        flutterEngine
            .getPlatformViewsController()
            .getRegistry()
            .registerViewFactory("<platform-view-type>", new NativeViewFactory());
    }
```

Comment: refer to this for complete tutorial https://codingwithtashi.medium.com/flutter-platformview-how-to-host-native-android-and-ios-view-in-flutter-79259faebd91

Answer (score 6):

Here is working code to display a native Android Textview in Flutter.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp( home: Native() );
}

class Native extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded( child: AndroidView(viewType: "view1",) ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.native_view_test;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        flutterEngine
                .getPlatformViewsController()
                .getRegistry()
                .registerViewFactory("view1", new NativeViewFactory());
    }
}
```

NativeViewFactory.java

```
package com.example.native_view_test;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.Map;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory;

class NativeViewFactory extends PlatformViewFactory {

    NativeViewFactory() {
        super(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformView create(@NonNull Context context, int id, @Nullable Object args) {
        final Map<String, Object> creationParams = (Map<String, Object>) args;
        return new NativeView(context, id, creationParams);
    }
}
```

NativeView.java

```
package com.example.native_view_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Map;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView;

class NativeView implements PlatformView {
    private final TextView textView;

    NativeView(Context context, int id, Map<String, Object> creationParams) {
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setTextSize(42);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        textView.setText("Rendered on a native Android view (id: " + id + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

Comment: This works for me I just need to change the text  BackgroundColor. Because flutter default background is white and android textview default colour is white. so initially you might not able to see the text but it is rendering.

Comment: This takes the whole screen of the Flutter app. Is there a way to use it with fixed size like textView.height = 80, like a normal Text Widget for Flutter?

Comment: And what about the edittext,scrollview etc. ? I have rendered the native edittext inplace of TextView but not able to enter any keyboard value to it. Also I have problem with Scrollview as well, Scrollview doesnot scroll (horizontal,vertical)

Comment: Note that this solution is for Virtual display where from the documentation keyboard handling and accessibility features may not work (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views?tab=android-platform-views-kotlin-tab)